# Another annoying JavaScript click event issue

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

```
var Home = document.getElementById("home");
var Page = document.getElementById("page");

Home.onclick = function(){Page.innerHTML = "I TYPED A BUNCH OF HTML HERE";};
```

Why is this not working? Nothing happens to the div id="page" when I click the div id="home" element.

**Note: This is plain Javascript linked between script tags in a .js document**

Edit: I tried using the Event Listener method.

```
Home.addEventListener("click", function(){Page.innerHTML = "

ALL THE HTML HERE

";
});
```

Still, nothing happens to the div id "page" when the div id "home" is clicked.
Tried running in IE and Chrome.

Comment: What is Page? Did you try a console.log inside the function?

Comment: use addEventListener to attach the event no ?

Comment: `Page` - C# programming background?

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: Console shows: Invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: @V.Snow The 2nd snippet can cause that with the `innerHTML` value. Single- and double-quoted string literals are not permitted to be multi-line / contain line-breaks.

Comment: Tried putting the HTML on one line ending with the "; . No difference. :/

Answer (score 0):

See the below example it runs perfectly.

But remember the element should be loaded before the event listener is attached.

I would recommend you put the below code at the bottom of the page like after closing the body tag.

Or calling the code on the document onload like so:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //ATTACH THE CLICK LISTENER HERE    
});
```

```js
var Home = document.getElementById("home");
Home.onclick = function(){
  alert("click happened");
};
```

```html
<div id="home">This is the div with id home</div>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything either. Does the HTML in the quotes in any way affect the Javascript document from running?

Answer (score 0):

> This is plain Javascript linked between script tags in a .js document

If it is a .js document, there is no need of `<script></script>` tag.

Try the below code snippet:

```js
 var Home = document.getElementById("home");
 var Page = document.getElementById("page");
    
 Home.onclick = function(){
 Page.innerHTML = "I TYPED A BUNCH OF HTML HERE";
};
```

```html
  <div id="home">  Home </div>
  <div id="page">   </div>
```

You should concatenate your text to the element's innerHTML instead of assigning.

Comment: This works as it should in the test area there, and my code is identical to that. But it doesn't work when I run the page. I'm thinking it has something to do with the contained HTML.

Comment: Console says "Invalid or unexpected token."